# AdModule Architecture using Abstract Factory Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, unity-game-engine, architecture

[image: UML Diagram]

I'm making this as a sample project in Unity. AdManager is a singleton Monobehaviour all other entities are C# files. I would like to discuss the architecture of this module. The diagram is not complete because the free version of the tool only supported this much. My basic requirements are simple **Develop an Ad module that shows ads on multiple platforms catering multiple ad networks. Can be easily integrated into any project.**

How I'm thinking of implementing it: Client only interacts with the AdManager which will be provided a PlatformAdController using AbstractFactory pattern. AdNetworkController will implement its corresponding AdNetwork. Then according to need multiple (Waterfall) AdNetworkController can be present in a PlatformAdController.

Am I going in the right direction?

What would be a good name for the Interface?

How to implement the lower(AdNetwork) layer i.e. Is there a need of interface/baseClass?

Comment: You are building an **Ad Network Mediation** tool like [MoPub](http://www.mopub.com/resources/ad-network-support/). Just saying in case you didn't know about them. Cheers.

Comment: I know about mopub and fyber .. try fyber its better :) And I'm implementing fyber for both IOS and Android. you can say AdMediator will also act as a Wrapped AdNetwork in the UML diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has build platform directives. Use them at compile time for better performance. Read more here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

Your approach is ok, but in case some of ads controller need additional action (for example update its state or something) you have to add new method to interface and this will be unused with other 100500 implementations. You can also create base `AdsBase : IAds` class and make empty virtual method stubs to not override each of them in classes that don't need them

Comment: I guess Im using Factory here to decouple the Mess you get in one file with Platform Directives. Ofcourse the class that will make the factory object will use these Platform Directives to make a PlatformAdController.

And about second part. Yes you are right. I can make factory with a base class instead of Interface. 
But doesnt the Abstract factory can have only Abstract method and by changing it we are violating it.
What would be a good name of the class that creates the PlatformAdControllers/Factory Objects  e.g. FactoryProducer ?